# SSRS - Log user's actions on reports

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008-r2

We want to log every user action(display/print/export) on certain reports of our application. I found that SSRS already have its log(select * from ExecutionLog) and most of the data we need is there BUT that log can be turned off if someone has access to the server. Is there an API/class we could to do that logging by our own?

We need a reliable solution where we are 100% sure that the log of the report is performed every time.

We are trying to avoid the use of events in the client side to log the user actions due to the network performance. Not sure if that is a recommendable option instead.

Any comment is appreciated :D

Comment: wouldn't it be simpler to not give end users access to the report server to turn off the logging?

Comment: Hi jMEm, this questions seems off-topic to me. Its not specific programming problem, but rather administration. It may also be too broad to answer. I think this would be better suited for [sf].

Comment: It sounds more like you need to lock down permissions on the server. Then you can just use the builtin logging in SSRS.

Comment: Thanks! I should have given more details. We sell our software so we cannot controll who access what after install. Also, the logging from SSRS is good but we still need to log some more data(from which menu option was printed/viewed, application user name, plus some other application-specific data)